# How to rename only the first found duplicate acrofield in pdf?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

On my PDF I have a duplicate field named Text1. Now I want to rename the first found acrofield with the name Text1 to foobar. The other field with name Text1 should be unchanged so that my new form contains the fields Text1 and foobar.

I am using the itext library and there the rename function but this method will rename all fields with name Text1 to foobar.

If someone wants to test it with my pdf, [here is a link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=34970992934525199618).

```
public class RenameField
{
    public static final String SRC = "c:\\test_duplicate_field2.pdf";
    public static final String DEST = "c:\\test_duplicate_field_mod.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws DocumentException, IOException
    {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new RenameField().manipulatePdf(SRC, DEST);
    }

    public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest)
        throws DocumentException, IOException
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
        form.renameField("Text1", "foobar");
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
        reader = new PdfReader(dest);
        form = reader.getAcroFields();
        Map<String, AcroFields.Item> fields = form.getFields();
        for (String name : fields.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach was to iterate through the AcroField.Items. If there is an item which has more then one values dictionaries (in this case the field exists more than one time) the change will be done.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, AcroFields.Item> entry: fieldMap.entrySet())
{
    // extract Values for Field
    String fieldKey = entry.getKey();

    AcroFields.Item item = entry.getValue();
    PdfDictionary dict;

    int numberOfDuplicates = item.values.size();

    if (numberOfDuplicates > 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDuplicates; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                log.info("first field wont be changed");
            } else {
                log.info("renaming field " + fieldKey + " round " + i );
                item.getMerged(i).put(PdfName.T, new PdfString(fieldKey + "_" + i ));
                item.getValue(i).put(PdfName.T, new PdfString(fieldKey + "_" + i));                     
                form.regenerateField(fieldKey); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this leads to the same result as the above approach with the renameField function from itext, both field names will be changed. During debugging I could see that the two value dictionarys of the item have the same object-id so when i change the value the dictionary[0] the value will change in dictionary[1] as well

[image]

Comment: You are confusing the concepts of fields and widget annotations. You have **one field** named Text1. This field has two widget annotations. When you rename Text1, you rename **one field** and that **one field** still has two widget annotations. Basically, I am saying that your question is wrong. You say you have two fields, but that's not true. You only have one field (with two widget annotations).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, obviously you are right that I am confusing the concepts. Do you have sample code how to rename one of the two widgets annotations instead of the field?

Answer (score 2):

> On my PDF I have a duplicate field named Text1

As Bruno already explained in a comment this is wrong. Your PDF has only a single field named "Text1":

```
34 0 obj
<</DA(/Helv 12 Tf 0 g)/FT/Tx/Kids[28 0 R 29 0 R]/T(Text1)>>
endobj
```

This single field has two kids

```
28 0 obj
<</F 4/MK<<>>/P 3 0 R/Parent 34 0 R/Rect[70.305 698.209 220.305 720.209]/Subtype/Widget/Type/Annot>>
endobj
29 0 obj
<</DA(/Helv 12 Tf 0 g)/F 4/MK<<>>/P 3 0 R/Parent 34 0 R/Rect[240.02 697.453 390.02 719.453]/Subtype/Widget/Type/Annot>>
endobj
```

These kids are mere widget annotations, **they are not fields in their own right.**

Thus, your request

> sample code how to rename one of the two widgets annotations instead of the field

does not make sense: *There is not one of two to rename* as only fields are named and there only is one field.

What you have to do is to create a new field named "foobar" (copying all attributes of the original field except **Kids** and **T**) and then move one of the Text1 kids to foobar.

Example code focusing on your use case:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(resource);

PdfDictionary form = reader.getCatalog().getAsDict(PdfName.ACROFORM);
PdfArray fields = form.getAsArray(PdfName.FIELDS);
for (PdfObject object: fields)
{
    PdfDictionary field = (PdfDictionary) PdfReader.getPdfObject(object);
    if ("Text1".equals(field.getAsString(PdfName.T).toString()))
    {
        PdfDictionary newField = new PdfDictionary();
        PRIndirectReference newFieldRef = reader.addPdfObject(newField);
        fields.add(newFieldRef);
        newField.putAll(field);
        newField.put(PdfName.T, new PdfString("foobar"));
        PdfArray newKids = new PdfArray();
        newField.put(PdfName.KIDS, newKids);
        PdfArray kids = field.getAsArray(PdfName.KIDS);
        PdfObject widget = kids.remove(0);
        newKids.add(widget);
        PdfDictionary widgetDict = (PdfDictionary) PdfReader.getPdfObject(widget);
        widgetDict.put(PdfName.PARENT, newFieldRef);
        break;
    }
}

PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, result);
stamper.close();
```

*([SameFieldTwice.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/form/SameFieldTwice.java) method `testWidgetToField`)*

Obviously for a generically usable solution there is much to do still.

Comment: Thank you for answering this @mkl, I currently don't have much time to answer questions.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. In the meantime I created a solution which first detects the duplicate fields, deletes them and at last recreates them with a new names but this has the bad side effect that not all appearances are as before. With your approach this side effect will be eliminated, so I will check this. Thanks

Comment: I have a small problem with your solution, duplicate fields which are grouped will not be changed because PdfName.T returns only the value before the dot. For example if you have the field test1.foobar1 as duplicate on the form, then it wont be changed because PdfName.T returns only test1.. How can I retrieve the complete name here?

Comment: That's why I wrote *Obviously for a generically usable solution there is much to do still.*  The code only looks at the first level of the fields tree. You will have to walk the tree. And again You talk about *the field test1.foobar1 as duplicate on the form*... The field is no duplicate, it merely has multiple widgets but it is a single field.